# How should I correct this pointer issue, it's giving me an error

Tags: c++, pointers, image-segmentation

Suppose rgbapixel is a class of pixels in rgbapixel.h file, so it has colors like green, blue, red as public members. PNG is a class of images in png.h file, so it has image width and height as private members, then it has two public functions that return width and height.

in my main.cpp, here is the code;

```
// sets up the output image
PNG * setupOutput(int w, int h)
{
    PNG * image = new PNG(w, h);
    return image;
}
void sketchify()
{   
    // Load in.png
       PNG * original = new PNG;
    original->readFromFile("in.png");
    int width  = original->width();
    int height = original->height();

    // Create out.png
     // PNG * output;                  // i change this
    PNG * output = new PNG;
     setupOutput(width, height);

    // Loud our favorite color to color the outline
    RGBAPixel * myPixel = myFavoriteColor(192);

    // Go over the whole image, and if a pixel differs from that to its upper
    // left, color it my favorite color in the output
    for (int y = 1; y < height; y++)
    {
            for (int x = 1; x < width; x++)
            {
                    // Calculate the pixel difference
                    RGBAPixel * prev = (*original)(x-1, y-1);      // previous top lfet
                    RGBAPixel * curr = (*original)(x  , y  );        // current

                                        // subtracting to see diffrence between pixels
                    int diff = abs(curr->red   - prev->red  ) +
                                       abs(curr->green - prev->green) +
                                       abs(curr->blue  - prev->blue );

                    // If the pixel is an edge pixel,
                    // color the output pixel with my favorite color

                    RGBAPixel * currOutPixel = (*output)(x,y);
                    if (diff > 100)
                            currOutPixel = myPixel;          // something wrong
            }
    }
    // Save the output file
    output->writeToFile("out.png");
    // Clean up memory
    delete myPixel;
    delete output;
    delete original;
```

When I execute the code, I get errors like;

```
[EasyPNG]: Warning: attempted to access non-existent pixel (407, 306);
        Truncating request to fit in the range [0,0] x [0,0].

[EasyPNG]: Warning: attempted to access non-existent pixel (408, 306);
        Truncating request to fit in the range [0,0] x [0,0].
```

Where I write "something is wrong", I have been told that there is an error there. I don't see it. 'mypixel' and currout where both declared successfully as pointers, so I don't see how that statement would be wrong. If I try to change it, I get compilation errors. help

Comment: I don't see any place where you are setting the size of output.

Comment: I don't see any place where "EasyPNG" is output, which means this is _not_ your [testcase](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `setupOutput(width, height);` does not do anything useful. It create a new `PNG` on the heap but the returned value is discarded. You end with two problems:

1. `output` does not have its width and height properly set.
2. There is a memory leak.

You can fix that using one of two approaches.

1. Assign the return value of `setupOutput(width, height)` to `output`.

   Replace the lines:

   ```
   PNG * output = new PNG;
   setupOutput(width, height);
   ```

   with

   ```
   PNG * output = setupOutput(width, height);
   ```
2. Don't use `setupOutput(width, height);` at all. Create a `PNG` inline.

   Replace the lines:

   ```
   PNG * output = new PNG;
   setupOutput(width, height);
   ```

   with

   ```
   PNG * output = new PNG(width, height);
   ```

No guarantees that these changes will fix all your problems.

**Update, in response to comment by OP**

The line

```
                        currOutPixel = myPixel;          // something wrong
```

doesn't do anything useful either. It just overrides where the local variable `currOutPixel` points. Assuming that it is OK to assign objects of type `RGBAPixel`, you need:

```
                        *currOutPixel = *myPixel;
```

Comment: so nothing is wrong with " currOutPixel = myPixel; "..... the TA told me that there was something around there